# How to make function accessing word values without segfault

Tags: c

The code compiles without warnings and errors, but I get segmentation fault. When I call function to add value to others in 4096 byte block. How to get this error away and make function correct?

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void addn_u16(unsigned short* _dataEnd, unsigned short* _data, unsigned short val)
{
    while (_data < _dataEnd)
    {
        unsigned short dat = *_data + val;
        *_data = dat;
        _data++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    clock_t begin = clock();

    unsigned short* block = malloc(4096);

    addn_u16(block + 4096, block, 645);

    clock_t ms = clock() - begin;

    printf("ms: %u", ms);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the malloc call, you are allocating 4096 bytes, you should pass `4096 * sizeof(unsigned short)` to malloc()

EDIT: you said in a comment that you intended to allocate 2048 shorts. Then you should pass `block + 2048` to `addn_u16`, because `block + 4096` will actually add an offset equal to 4096 * sizeof(short): [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_pointer_arithmatic.htm) is how pointer's arithmetic works

Comment: it's not problem with mallloc, you can have 2048 shorts which occupies 4096 bytes.

Comment: I forgot arithmetic logic with pointers, I assumed 4096 is bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the issue is that `sizeof(unsigned short)` is not 1. According the C standard, it must be **at least 16 bits, or 2 bytes**

> Any compiler conforming to the Standard must also respect the following limits with respect to the range of values any particular type may accept. Note that these are lower limits: an implementation is free to exceed any or all of these. Note also that the minimum range for a char is dependent on whether or not a char is considered to be signed or unsigned. ... short int: -32767 to +32767.

When you do-

```c
unsigned short* block = malloc(4096);
```

You're allocating `4096` 1 byte memory slots. But in this case, you'd need double of that.

This will do the trick-

```c
unsigned short* block = malloc(4096 * sizeof(unsigned short));
```

But, here's a better and more preferred way for maintainable code-

```c
unsigned short* block = malloc(4096 * sizeof(*block));
```

This way, even if the type of `block` changed, you wouldn't have to change the `sizeof`.

I'd also like to add `%u` is not the correct way of printing a `clock_t` variable. Now, there really isn't a way to know whether `clock_t` will be an integer or a double, but it's always preferred to divide `clock_t` by `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get human understandable number.

Then you could use-

```c
printf("ms: %f\n", (double) ms / CLOCKS_PER_SEC * 1000);
```